# Hollow of a polygon in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I have tried to fill a gap in a polygon in QGIS, but the tool that uses QGIS instead of that draws another polygon over the gap that I want to eliminate.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to fill a gap in a polygon hole without drawing a new polygon, you can use delete ring tool as shown below:

[image]

Then put the mouse pointer (cursor) above the hole and using the mouse left-click the gap will be deleted:

Before:

[image]

When you click over the hole (gap):

[image]

Final result:

[image]